# Select rows from table where value equals value from another table

Tags: mysql

Aliases

> id domain_id source destination

Domains

> id name

I want to select source from Aliases where id ( from domains ) equals domain_id from aliases

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT source FROM aliases WHERE domain_id IN(SELECT * FROM domains WHERE id="2")
```

I want to have source where domain_id = 2.
I can't do it like this: `SELECT source FROM aliases WHERE domain_id = 2`
Because 2 will be provided from user privileges

Comment: Offtopic: i assume id column to be a INT ?  if so you should be using `id = 2`  instead..

Comment: good point, thank you

Comment: Double qoutes in SQL language is meant for indentifiers like database, table, column names or aliases meaning   `SELECT "source" FROM "aliases" WHERE "domain_id"` ... Single qoutes is meant for string datatype meaning `SELECT "source" FROM "aliases" WHERE "domain_id" IN(SELECT * FROM "domains" WHERE "id" = '2' )` if id column would be a CHAR/VARCHAR type   well the double qoutes for indentifiers only works when you enable a sql_mode in MySQL otherwise you get a error ..

Comment: @RaymondNijland it works with "" and ''.

Comment: But back ontopic: ... See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: *"it works with "" and ''"* Yes i know MySQL is loose with single/double qoutes for string values , but try to use the writing style i said as it  makes stepping over or learning a other RDMS much more easy  when you follow the ANSI SQL standard a bit more..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.source
FROM aliases a 
INNER JOIN domains d ON a.id = d.id
WHERE a.domain_id = 2;
```

Using INNER JOIN between these 2 tables will provide the answer you wish for, INNER JOIN are used just for case like that but you of course can use the way you used ( sub query ) by doing the following :

```
SELECT a.source 
FROM aliases a 
WHERE a.domain_id IN(SELECT d.id FROM domains d WHERE d.id=2)
```

edit: I'm always using an letters to describe the table I'm using for the query, easier to find the columns you have in each table.

Comment: The second can't work if there are more than one column because "SELECT *" will return all columns and it will result in an error...

Comment: @Gosfly , correct, forgot to change his sub query :)